# Android Studio Launching Issue

Tags: android

Android studio installed but when launching it is showing 
"Failed to download 'http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r22.6.2-windows.zip': dl.google.com

Answer (score 0):

if you are downloading on chrome browser, then it gives a problem at finish of download. Try using mozilla firefox browser to download.

I had also faced this issue before.

Comment: u means i have to download Android studio again by  using mozilla firefox??

Comment: NorthCat : i add proxy and port in config file . then it was starting downloading this and it will take @20 hr to download whole sdk

Comment: Fahim   :i download Android studio using mozilla firefox . and installed it but again it force me to add proxy for internet and start down loading from net .Is there is any other way to  use android studio without internet

Comment: offline download not possible